# how to create excel sheet which contain maximum 30 sheets in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to create excel from datatable, And want to create maximum 25 sheets(each day for current month excluding weekend, Saturday,Sunday and bank holiday) , how can we do this by taking string of array for total days in month and datatable.

```
Public static void CreateExcel_TabNameUnique( DataTable dt1,string ExcelFilePath, string Tab_Name1)
 {
   try
   {
       runDate = DateTime.Today;
       currMonth = DateTime.Today;
       object missing = Type.Missing;
       Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
       oXL.Visible = false;
       Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(missing);
       Excel.Worksheet oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
       oSheet.Name = Tab_Name1;
       // column headings
       for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Columns.Count; i++)
       {
           oSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = dt1.Columns[i].ColumnName;
       }
       // rows
       for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Columns.Count; j++)
           {
               oSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = dt1.Rows[i][j];
           }
       }
       if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
       {
           try
           {
               oWB.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,
           missing, missing, missing, missing,
           Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
           missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
               oWB.Close(missing, missing, missing);
               oXL.UserControl = true;
               oXL.Quit();
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
           }
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
```

}

Comment: Okay and what else you tried so far ?

Comment: I know only how to create excel using interlope in c#, please refer my updated question.

Comment: What is you problem exactly?

Comment: @AlexButenko- I know  how to create one sheet in one excel. with one datatable, but I want to create multiple sheet in one excel like mention above in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not being able to verify this at the moment (problems with Excel Interop...), but from your comment I take it your problem is just in adding a second worksheet. You should be able to do this with:

```
Excel.Worksheet secondWorkSheet = oWB.Worksheets.Add();
```

Then proceed to manipulate worksheet as you are doing in the code you posted.